# Java chain lock a bit differently

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 1,2,3 threads each have A,B,C sections to run sequentially like
1A, 2A, 3A, 1B, 2B, 3B, 1C, 2C, 3C. So after 1A finishes its run it waits for the signal of thread 3 to continue with its section B and so on. How could I achieve this? I have to reuse the threads so I cannot make threads from sections.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to use multiple ReentrantLock, synchronized, wait, notify.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?  And what are the results you have gotten?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: I haven't got so far. I was able to run 1A, 2A, 3A only so I thought it is not useful to share but if you insist.

Comment: If the threads are so tightly coupled, why use threads at all? You can just run the sections one after the other in the correct order.

Comment: Do you need the sequence of 1A, 2A, 3A to stay in that order? If so, then I don't see any reason to use Threads because you have a serial application.

Comment: I have to use threads because selenide forces one webdriver per thread and I want to run 3 browsers parallelly. I know that selenide can run multiple browsers from version 5 but that way it is not compatible with my code.
Yes, I need the sequence of 1A, 2A, 3A to stay in that order.

Answer (score 2):

That's the job of a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

```
public class BarrierDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(3); // three threads

        new Thread(new Task(1, barrier)).start();
        new Thread(new Task(2, barrier)).start();
        new Thread(new Task(3, barrier)).start();
    }

    private static class Task implements Runnable {
        private final int number;
        private final CyclicBarrier barrier;

        public Task(int number, CyclicBarrier barrier) {
            this.number = number;
            this.barrier = barrier;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(number + "A");
                barrier.await();
                System.out.println(number + "B");
                barrier.await();
                System.out.println(number + "C");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch(BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // too bad
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this run the tasks in batchs (1A, 2A, 3A) then (1B, 2B, 3B) where the order of the A tasks could be in any order? The order of the B tasks could be in any order, etc.

Comment: This doesn't ensure that threads will run a task in order 1,2,3

Comment: @matt yes. I assume that this is what the OP wants. Otherwise, if everything needs to be run sequentially, there is no point in using threads at all.

Answer (score 0):

if order of 1,2,3 is not important , but order of all A,all B,all C is important, Then,
use 2 CountDownLatch.
you can start A section directly . when A section is done count down the CountDownLatch.

before B section starts await() the CountDownLatch.

so there should be 2 CountDownLatch latches to synchronize section B and section C.

```
    public class Test extends Thread
{

  CountDownLatch cdlA;
  CountDownLatch cdlB;
  int threadId;

  public Test(CountDownLatch cdlA, CountDownLatch cdlB,int threadNumber)
  {
    this.cdlA = cdlA;
    this.cdlB = cdlB;
    threadId = threadNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    test();
  }

  private   void test()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("section A" +threadId);
      cdlA.countDown();

      cdlA.await();

      System.out.println("section B" +threadId);
      cdlB.countDown();

      cdlB.await();

      System.out.println("section C" +threadId);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {

    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    CountDownLatch a = new CountDownLatch(3);
    CountDownLatch b = new CountDownLatch(3);

    final Test test1 = new Test(a, b,1);

    final Test test2 = new Test(a, b,2);

    final Test test3 = new Test(a, b,3);

    test1.start();
    test2.start();
    test3.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a delegate that knows what to do then you can use an executor service to control execution. Eg. create an executors service for each thread, submit, then use Future.get to wait for the execution completes.

The otherway is to use a sort of ball.

```
static public void task(int no){
    System.out.println("task " + no + " on " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BlockingQueue<Object> permissions = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

    var A = new Thread(){
        BlockingQueue<Object> waiting = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
        public void run(){
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                Object ball = null;
                try{
                    ball = waiting.take();
                    task(i);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }finally{
                    permissions.offer(ball);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var B = new Thread(){
        BlockingQueue<Object> waiting = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
        public void run(){
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                Object ball = null;
                try{
                    ball = waiting.take();
                    task(i);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }finally{
                    permissions.offer(ball);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    A.start();
    B.start();
    Object ball = new Object();
    A.waiting.offer(ball);
    ball = permissions.take();
    B.waiting.offer(ball);
    ball = permissions.take();
    A.waiting.offer(ball);
    ball = permissions.take();
    B.waiting.offer(ball);
    ball = permissions.take();
    A.waiting.offer(ball);
    ball = permissions.take();
    B.waiting.offer(ball);
    ball = permissions.take();
    System.out.println("finished");
```

There are definitely better ways, I think you can see this is not extensible, you have to know the number of tasks. There is no actuall purpose for the Object ball, and a new Object(); could be used, or even null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for the problem. I think the idea behind it is close to matt's solution. Thank you for all you guys.

```
 @Test
void test() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    SynchronousQueue<Integer> chromeQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    SynchronousQueue<Integer> firefoxQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();
    SynchronousQueue<Integer> ieQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();

    Runnable ieRunnable = () -> {
        try {
            firefoxQueue.take();
            System.out.println("ieRunnable section 1");
            ieQueue.put(1);
            firefoxQueue.take();
            System.out.println("ieRunnable section 2");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    };

    Runnable firefoxRunnable = () -> {
        try {
            chromeQueue.take();
            System.out.println("firefoxRunnable section 1");
            firefoxQueue.put(1);
            chromeQueue.take();
            System.out.println("firefoxRunnable section 2");
            firefoxQueue.put(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    Runnable chromeRunnable = () -> {
        try {
            ieQueue.take();//waits    
            System.out.println("chromeRunnable section 1");
            chromeQueue.put(1);//starts firefoxRunnable
            ieQueue.take();//wait for ieRunnable to signal
            System.out.println("chromeRunnable section 2");
            chromeQueue.put(1);//makes firefoxRunnable to continue
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    executor.execute(chromeRunnable);
    executor.execute(firefoxRunnable);
    executor.execute(ieRunnable);
    ieQueue.put(1);
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```